# Lehmer's problem over a finite field

Tags: prime-numbers

Does there exist an odd prime $p>3$, and integers $m>2$ and  $n_k>0$ such that

$$ p^{\sum_{k=1}^m n_k} \equiv 1 \bmod \prod_{k=1}^m (p^{n_k}-1) ? $$

where  if some n_i are the same , the same number appears at most r(n,p) times.
r(n,p) is the number of irreducible polynomials of degree n over the finite field F_p.

Comment: m is larger than 1 

Comment: Yes, for example $p=3$. See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81816/a-question-on-divisibility-of-a-product-of-primes

Comment: It may be helpful, if you could provide more background about your question. In particular, why do you need p>3 and what's the reason for the condition involving r(n,p) ? 

Comment: the decomposition of a polynomial